Multi Step Record Creation Form with Validation Using Formik, Yup, and MUI
This component is a multistep popup form designed to handle job vacancy creation. It uses MUI for the UI, Formik and Yup for form handling and validation. The form is divided into 4 steps: Job Details, Compensation, Skills & Requirements, and Process & Reapplication for a simple user experience. Each step includes specific fields validated with Yup. Users can navigate between steps and validation ensures required fields are completed before proceeding.
All of this works fine. But I'm looking for any suggestions mainly about typescript and architecture that I can improve or I'm doing wrong. I'd greatly appreciate that.
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Divider,
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  IconButton,
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
} from '@mui/material';
import { Close as CloseIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Formik, Form, FormikErrors, FormikTouched } from 'formik'; // Importing Formik for form handling and validation
import * as Yup from 'yup'; // Importing Yup for schema based validation
import StepOne from './steps/StepOne'; // Import StepOne component for the first step of the form
import StepTwo from './steps/StepTwo'; // Import StepTwo component for the second step of the form
import StepThree from './steps/StepThree'; // Import StepThree component for the third step of the form
import StepFour from './steps/StepFour'; // Import StepFour component for the fourth step of the form

// Array of step titles that will be shown in the Stepper component for navigation
const steps = [
  'Job Details',
  'Compensation',
  'Skills & Requirements',
  'Process & Reapplication',
];

// Array of components corresponding to each form step
const stepsComponents = [<StepOne />, <StepTwo />, <StepThree />, <StepFour />];

const dialogActionStyles = {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  gap: 2,
  py: 2,
  backgroundColor: '#f7f9fa',
  borderRadius: '6px',
};

// Define the prop types for the VacancyCreate component
interface VacancyCreateProps {
  open: boolean; // Controls whether the dialog is open
  setOpen: (newValue: boolean) => void; // Function to set the open state
}

// Define the shape of the form values object
interface FormValues {
  positionTitle: string;
  location: string | null;
  jobLevel: Record<string, unknown> | null;
  hiringManager: Record<string, unknown> | null;
  recruitFor: string | null;
  travelRequired: string;
  jobDescription: string;
  functionalArea: string;
  minPay: number;
  maxPay: number;
  internalResponsible: string | null;
  automata: string | null;
  reapplicationWaitingPeriod: number;
  reapplicationPeriodUnit: string;
  currency: string;
  responsibilities: string;
  skillsRequired: string;
  educationalRequirements: string;
}

// Initial values for the form fields
const initialValues: FormValues = {
  positionTitle: '', // Default empty string for position title
  location: '', // Default empty string for location
  jobLevel: null, // Default value of null for job level
  hiringManager: null, // Default value of null for hiring manager
  recruitFor: null, // Default value of null for recruit for field
  travelRequired: '', // Default empty string for travel required field
  jobDescription: '', // Default empty string for job description field
  functionalArea: '', // Default empty string for functional area field
  minPay: 0, // Default minimum pay is 0
  maxPay: 0, // Default maximum pay is 0
  internalResponsible: null, // Default value of null for internal responsible field
  automata: null, // Default value of null for automata field
  reapplicationWaitingPeriod: 3, // Default value of 3 for reapplication waiting period
  reapplicationPeriodUnit: 'months', // Default value of 'months' for the reapplication period unit
  currency: '', // Default empty string for currency
  responsibilities: '', // Default empty string for responsibilities
  skillsRequired: '', // Default empty string for skills required
  educationalRequirements: '', // Default empty string for educational requirements
};

// Grouping the fields into arrays for each step to control validation and rendering
const stepFieldGroups: Array<Array<keyof FormValues>> = [
  [
    'positionTitle',
    'location',
    'jobLevel',
    'hiringManager',
    'recruitFor',
    'travelRequired',
    'jobDescription',
    'functionalArea',
  ],
  ['minPay', 'maxPay', 'currency'],
  ['responsibilities', 'skillsRequired', 'educationalRequirements'],
  [
    'internalResponsible',
    'automata',
    'reapplicationWaitingPeriod',
    'reapplicationPeriodUnit',
  ],
];

// Defining the validation schema using Yup for each field in the form
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  positionTitle: Yup.string()
    .max(50)
    .required('Position Title is a required field'),
  location: Yup.string().nullable(),
  currency: Yup.string().nullable(),
  responsibilities: Yup.string().nullable(),
  skillsRequired: Yup.string().nullable(),
  educationalRequirements: Yup.string().nullable(),
  jobLevel: Yup.object().required('Job Level is a required field'),
  hiringManager: Yup.object().required('Hiring Manager is a required field'),
  recruitFor: Yup.mixed().nullable(),
  automata: Yup.mixed().nullable(),
  internalResponsible: Yup.mixed().nullable(),
  travelRequired: Yup.string().max(150).nullable(),
  jobDescription: Yup.string().nullable(),
  functionalArea: Yup.string().max(150).nullable(),
  reapplicationWaitingPeriod: Yup.number().required(
    'Reapplication Waiting Period is required'
  ),
  minPay: Yup.number()
    .min(0, 'Min pay must be greater than or equal to 0')
    .max(99999999.99, 'Min pay must be less than or equal to 99,999,999.99')
    .required('Min pay is required'),
  maxPay: Yup.number()
    .min(0, 'Max pay must be greater than or equal to 0')
    .max(99999999.99, 'Max pay must be less than or equal to 99,999,999.99')
    .required('Max pay is required'),
});

// Helper function to handle validation errors and set the appropriate form errors and touched fields
const handleValidationErrors = (
  err: Yup.ValidationError, // Yup validation error object
  currentStepFields: string[], // Fields for the current step
  setErrors: (errors: FormikErrors<FormValues>) => void, // Function to set form errors
  setTouched: (
    touched: FormikTouched<FormValues>,
    shouldValidate?: boolean
  ) => void // Function to set form touched status
) => {
  const errors = err.inner.reduce((acc: FormikErrors<FormValues>, error) => {
    acc[error.path as keyof FormValues] = error.message; // Assign the error message to the field
    return acc;
  }, {});

  // Mark the fields as touched to display validation errors
  const touchedFields = currentStepFields.reduce((acc, field) => {
    acc[field as keyof FormikTouched<FormValues>] = true; // Mark the field as touched
    return acc;
  }, {} as FormikTouched<FormValues>);

  setErrors(errors); // Set form errors
  setTouched(touchedFields, true); // Set form touched fields to show validation messages
};

// Main component to handle the vacancy creation form
export default function VacancyCreate({ open, setOpen }: VacancyCreateProps) {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0); // State to track the current form step

  // Function to close the dialog
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  // Function to move to the next step after validation
  const goToNextStep = async (
    values: FormValues, // Current form values
    setTouched: (
      touched: FormikTouched<FormValues>,
      shouldValidate?: boolean
    ) => void, // Function to mark fields as touched
    setErrors: (errors: FormikErrors<FormValues>) => void // Function to set validation errors
  ) => {
    const currentStepFields = stepFieldGroups[currentStep]; // Get the fields for the current step

    if (!currentStepFields) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Validate the fields for the current step using Yup.reach
      for (const field of currentStepFields) {
        const schema = Yup.reach(validationSchema, field) as Yup.Schema<any>; // Get the schema for the current field
        await schema.validate(values[field]); // Validate the current field's value
      }

      // If validation passes, proceed to the next step
      setCurrentStep((prevStep) => prevStep + 1);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Yup.ValidationError) {
        // If there is a validation error, call the error handler
        handleValidationErrors(err, currentStepFields, setErrors, setTouched);
      }
    }
  };

  // Function to move to the previous step
  const goToPreviousStep = () => setCurrentStep((prevStep) => prevStep - 1);

  // Check if the current step is the last one
  const isLastStep = currentStep === stepsComponents.length - 1;
  // Check if the current step is the first one
  const isFirstStep = currentStep === 0;

  return (
    <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth='md' open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
      <DialogTitle sx={{ textAlign: 'center', py: 1.3 }}>
        New Vacancy
      </DialogTitle>
      <IconButton
        aria-label='close'
        onClick={handleClose}
        sx={{ position: 'absolute', right: 8, top: 8 }}
      >
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Divider />
      <DialogContent sx={{ p: 0 }}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={() => {}}
        >
          {({ values, setTouched, setErrors }) => (
            <Form noValidate>
              <Box sx={{ px: 6, py: 4 }}>
                <Stepper activeStep={currentStep} alternativeLabel>
                  {steps.map((label) => (
                    <Step key={label}>
                      <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                  ))}
                </Stepper>

                {/* Render the current step component */}
                {stepsComponents[currentStep]}
              </Box>

              <Divider />

              <Box sx={dialogActionStyles}>
                <Button size='small' variant='outlined' onClick={handleClose}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>

                {!isFirstStep && (
                  <Button
                    size='small'
                    variant='outlined'
                    onClick={goToPreviousStep}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                )}

                {isLastStep ? (
                  <Button size='small' variant='contained' type='submit'>
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    size='small'
                    variant='contained'
                    onClick={() => goToNextStep(values, setTouched, setErrors)}
                  >
                    Next
                  </Button>
                )}
              </Box>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

